# OxyPlot - would like to add datapoint-specific thumbnail image to Tracker (WPF)

Tags: wpf, image, oxyplot

I have an image processing application that runs through a set of images, calculates a "score" for each image, and then plots a graph of the scores.  As I calculate the scores, I add them to an OxyPlot LineSeries giving me a time vs score graph.  The tracker works great, showing time and score value, but I'd like to add a small image thumbnail to the tracker if possible.  In other words, when I'm adding points to the LineSeries, I'd also like to add a reference to a thumbnail image, and then have that image displayed in the tracker.

EDIT:
I have used IDataPointProvider to create a custom type that allows me to attach extra data to my series points.  I then created List<> of this new type and assigned it as my series ItemsSource.  This all seems to work fine, but I still can't figure out a way to have the Tracker display an image.

```
private class MeasurementType1 : IDataPointProvider
    {
        public double Abscissa { get; set; }
        public double Ordinate { get; set; }
        public DateTime dateTime { get; set; }           
        public BitmapImage thumbnail { get; set; }            

        public MeasurementType1(double abscissa, double ordinate, BitmapImage thumb)
        {
            this.Abscissa = abscissa;
            this.Ordinate = ordinate;
            this.dateTime = DateTimeAxis.ToDateTime(abscissa);
            this.thumbnail = thumb;
        }

        public DataPoint GetDataPoint()
        {
            return new DataPoint(Abscissa, Ordinate);
        }
    }

List<MeasurementType1> itemsSource = new List<MeasurementType1>();

LineSeries m_series1 = new LineSeries();
m_series1.ItemsSource = itemsSource;
```

// XAML

```
<oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding}">
        <oxy:PlotView.DefaultTrackerTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <oxy:TrackerControl Position="{Binding Position}" LineExtents="{Binding LineExtents}">
                    <oxy:TrackerControl.Content>                            
                        <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
                    </oxy:TrackerControl.Content>
                </oxy:TrackerControl>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </oxy:PlotView.DefaultTrackerTemplate>
    </oxy:PlotView>
```

Comment: Have you tryed with a static image instead of a dynamic one? Just to reduce the posibilities..

Comment: @Kirenenko - I did.  It just doesn't seem to like an image in the tracker pop up for some reason.  There are samples that show a canvas with a different things drawn on the canvas.  I'm going to try putting the image on a canvas and see if that works.

Comment: I've tried with a static image and it worked for me. In resources -  `<BitmapImage x:Key="lockImage" UriSource="Images/lock.png" />` and in Plot view - <Image Name="image" Source="{StaticResource lockImage}" Width="20" Height="20"/>. Maybe is the type of the image what is not working.